# Does the Moto G7 Power support HDMI alt mode?

Tags: motorola, hdmi

I plugged my Moto G7 power into my audio/video receiver, with a high quality USB-C to HDMI cable. This same cable works with other devices, such as a Lenovo C330 Chromebook. Unfortunately, I am not getting any HDMI signal from my Android device. Apparently HDMI "alt mode" is required in order to support video output from Android devices, but I am not sure if the Moto G7 Power has this capability or not.

**Question**: How can I check if the Moto G7 Power supports [HDMI alt mode](https://www.hdmi.org/spec/typec)?

Comment: [check](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhl.checker.connector) if it supports Hdmi or not first. I don't think it does, else support page would have mentioned apart from Chrome cast https://support.motorola.com/us/en/solution/MS136519

Comment: AFAIK the "HDMI alt" mode is a nearly dead specification that was nearly never implemented because it came too late. The only alternative mode that is actively used is the Displayport alternative mode. Some adapters use Displayport alternative mode plus DP2HDMI chip to provide an HDMI output.